# Virtuemart Accordion only on certain pages

Tags: if-statement, joomla, virtuemart

I'm using Virtuemart 2.0.4 with Joomla 2.5. I'm not a star in Joomla!

I also use an accordion module to display the Virtuemart Categories. Now, I just want to show the accordion only when Virtuemart is loaded, in other words: When you are on the Webshop page, categorylist AND the specific product page.

I've already managed to make an if else statement for the frontpage, like so:

```
// IF IS HOMEPAGE 
   $menu = JSite::getMenu(); if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
} else {

}
```

I thought I could do the same with if virtuemart is loaded, like:

```
if ( $pageoption != 'com_virtuemart' )   { ?>
    DONT LOAD ACCORDION MENU
<?php } else { ?>
    LOAD ACCORDION MENU
<?php } ?>
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Do you guys have an idea how to accomplish such thing? Ty

Comment: I am interested in hearing a PHP solution, you might want to add that to your tags. But, there is a work around with jQuery searching for a main id then using the .remove() if true. You can make this work as an extension that does not alter PHP in Joomla and save some headaches when updates roll around.

Comment: -Also, you can create a new module position in your template for this menu only, then wrap conditional code for that module position. That would at least simplify half the selection. Just be careful if using pre-packaged template.. they love to rewrite your code in updates.

Answer (score 1):

a good solution for this is to use [MetaMod](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/3391). It has built-in functionality for detecting different VM page types, and can use this to trigger other modules (or not). You don't have to alter your template as it works in any template. The logic then goes into the MetaMod, and it decides when to include the other modules or not.

You accomplish this with a snippet of PHP code which you put into the MetaMod, returning the module id of the module that you want to display.

e.g. to detect any page in VM, and show the module:

```
if ($option == 'com_virtuemart') return XXX;
// replace XXX with the module id of the module to show.
```

You can also detect particular VM page types like this:

```
$vm = JomGenius("virtuemart");
if ($vm->check("pagetype = shop.product_details")) return XXX;
// shop.product_details is for VM1.x. Use "productdetails" for VM2.x.
if ($vm->check("pagetype startswith checkout")) return XXX;
// e.g. checkout.index#1-4, checkout.result, etc
```

You can find all the page types, and lots of other things you can query on, on the [JomGenius page](http://www.metamodpro.com/jomgenius/parameters#vm1x), e.g. detecting which category something is in, previous purchase history, manufacturer, particular details of the product being displayed, cart contents, etc. There are more examples [here](http://www.metamodpro.com/metamod/recipes/36-component-specific/76-control-modules-on-virtuemart-pages).